# And with an Or conditional statement in react / javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to disable a button depending on a couple of conditions.

```
<Button disabled={((myobject && myobject.name === "bob") || user.registered) ? true : false} >my button</Button>
```

Essentially, I want to disable the button if `myobject.name` is "bob" or if the user is registered (eg. user.registered is not nil). As it stands now, the button seems to get disabled if `myobject.name` is "bob" but it seems to ignore `user.registered`. What am I doing wrong?

many thanks!

Comment: Should work well

Comment: if it is not bob then it needs to rely on _registered_'s truthiness.  You should look at its explicit value.  Please build a reproducible example if you can and we will debug it.

Comment: The first part of the If statement is where the issue is.  `(myobject && myobject.name === "bob") ` myobject exsits so TRUE and myobject.name === "bob" so TRUE.  So since both are TRUE user.registered will not be evaluated because the first part of the OR statement is TRUE.  Disabled then gets set to true. There are two ways to fix the logic:
`((myobject && myobject.name !== "bob") || user.registered) ? true : false`
OR 
`((myobject && myobject.name === "bob") || user.registered) ? false: true`

Comment: @hajile78 I don't think that's correct. The statements work fine on their own so the issue is the combination of them

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote the other answers. I would if I could ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and by omitting the ternary, as it is redundant here:

```
<Button disabled={myobject?.name === "bob" || user.registered}>my button</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the button tag you could try to use just the two constraints you want to impose (I didn't understand why the myobject at the beginning though). It could be something like the following:

`(myobject.name === "bob" || user.registered) ? true : false`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're probably pretty close, the code you have should work fine. I would make sure to check two things. Make sure that user.registered has a "truthy" value.

If it's a string or a number it could be evaluating to false where you don't expect it. In Javascript `0` `undefined` `null` `""` (empty string) and `NaN` are all evaluated as `false`

You should also make sure that myobject is defined somewhere. You'll still get a reference error if myobject never gets declared. if myobject is any of those values that evaluate to false though and `user.registered == true` then your code should do what I think you're trying to accomplish. If not you might need to give a little more detail as to what you expect to happen and some sample values to look at.